# Auto stretch image with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 1905px wide image and I was hoping to make it auto resize to fit the width read by bootstrap. This doesn't seem to work :

```
<div class="body container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/Temp/WP_20140326_001.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do I have to use css width ? Thank you !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
.row > div > img { width: 100%; display: block; }
```

Answer (score 14):

Bootstrap has a helper class to help images to be responsive:

`.img-responsive`

Which, entails practically the same as Ken's answer:

```
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

#### [Bootstrap Github `.img-responsive`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1120)

Answer (score 0):

add this class that is for bootstrap

.img-responsive